# How to suppress the popup at the time of launching RDP

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdp

I have a website. Where in one page I am trying to launch RDP based on some key. Where one key can be associated to multiple Remote Desktop sessions. Now my requirement is to suppress the popup that is coming every time for each of the sessions. It's a bit annoying. Please help me. I am also bit new with such requirement. I have used C# for my web app.

![This is the pop up i want to supress.][1]

Comment: You seem to be missing the link to the popup.